# Derivation of path equation for automobile steering

Tags: geometry, derivatives

so I have this equation related to the picture. My problem is, I can’t see how the equation geometrically/mathematically makes any sense. The equation is true and returns the correct result when being used.

[image]

$R_{sp,3}$ is the radius that approximately goes where I have marked it with red on the picture. $d_{ki}$ and $b_v$ are both distances.

I don’t know if you need the equations for radius $R_{ki,1}$ og $R_{ki,2}$ but here they are ($V_p$ is just a number related to the specific case):

$$R_{ki,1} = \frac{1}{\dfrac{1}{R_{sp,3}}+\dfrac{108}{V_p^2}} \quad\text{and}\quad R_{ki,2} = \frac{1}{\dfrac{1}{R_{sp,3}\pm b_v}+\dfrac{108}{V_p^2}}$$

The equation I need help with is:

$$d_{ki} = R_{sp,3} + \sqrt{R_{sp,3} \cdot (R_{sp,3} \pm b_v)}$$

Can anyone tell me how that equation is derived?

Comment: Your question is so strange... You mention "radii", I don't think it is radii of curvature but **arcs of curves** ? Confirm it. Now what is the variable (I mean : what are the units on the abscissa axis ?) What is the context: Electrical Engineering, Mechanics ... etc.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion. The context is road engineering, where these equations help calculate the radius of the connection curves and different distances used to design a left turn lane and a width extension of the road. The equation was made by a clever engineer 50 years ago, and nobody (that i know of) has figured out how he made that equation since. 
Alle the units are in meters. 
R_sp,3 defines the radius of the connection curve between R_sp,1 and R_ki,1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have been working some time ago with curves connecting other curves ("trochoids", less simple than hyperbolas). I am still puzzled: as you will see: I have changed my graphics using the data you have provided but I still haven't connected curves... Can you confirm that the dotted line is the axis of abscissas for variable $x=R_{sp3}$ ? Can you confirm that the equations are equations of **curves** and not **radii of curvature** ?

Comment: I am not sure if the dotted line represents the axis of abscissas for R_sp,3. The dotted line in the picture just represents the centerline of the road, when there is no width extension happening. The equations must be equations of curves. They are just part of a circle that is a tangent to the connecting parts of a circle.

Comment: So, these equations should be radii of curvature (for example: "radius of curvature = constant" is an arc of circle, "radius of curvature constantly decreasing" is a piece of spiral, etc. The problem is "where are the centers of curvature" ?

Comment: Then the equations are radii of curvature. The centers is something i have a problem with too, because it is not defined anywhere. To draw this in CAD-programs, you do not need centers of curvature. All i know, is that all the arcs are a tangent to the connecting arc

Comment: Hi again, have you given up?

Comment: No, the reason is plainly that I was unable to retrieve your question( I hadn't kept any link to it).

Comment: Okay, thank you. Is there any more information you need?

Comment: I'm unclear what is happening here, and I am unable to replicate the situation based on the information given. Are you saying that the various sub-paths are *circular* arcs with the specified radii ($R_{sp,1}$, $R_{sp,3}$, $R_{ki,1}$, $R_{ki,2}$)? Or are they more-arbitrary curves (cubic splines?) that attain those radii-of-curvature somewhere (*where*?)? Could you provide the specific numerical values used to make the figure (or provide an alternative figure)? Can you provide an online reference for these equations?

Comment: Can you give examples of $d_{ki}$ and $R_{sp,3}$ ? It seems to me that $d$ should be a few meters, while $R$ would be much bigger. But then the equation can't be good ($d$ is similar to $2R$)

Comment: Perhaps ypu may get help better from https://engineering.stackexchange.com/ chek the "civil-engineering" tag

Comment: Blue: Yes, they are all cirbular arcs with the specified radii. I can link you to an online reference for the equations, but all the text is in danish (So not sure how that would help - and it doesn't specify the equations further). 
Ripi2: Examples of numbers for d_ki and R_sp,3 could be d_ki = 1,75 m and R_sp,3 = 533 m. R_sp,3 can vary alot depending on the specific case, while d_ki almost always will be in between 1,5-2 m.

Comment: @Math9876: The image pretty clearly suggests (and your commented sample values confirm) that $d_{ki}<R_{sp,3}$. But the target formula indicates $d_{ki}$ is *more* than $R_{sp_3}$. Should(n't) there be a $-$ before the square root?

Comment: @Math9876: Also, what exactly *is* $d_{ki}$? Is it the "vertical" distance from the inflection point to the "horizontal"? Is it the "vertical" distance from the inflection point to the red arc? Is it the distance from the inflection point "perpendicular" to the red arc? Something else? If $d_{ki}$ is not  actually "vertical", then do the $L_{ki}/2$ distances measure the horizontal distances between the landmark points on the roadway *upper* end of $d_{ki}$ (ie, the inflection point)? or the *lower* end?

Comment: @Math9876: Here's where I am with this: I setup some parameters and managed to get a path of circular arcs with appropriate tangencies at the three $L/2$-related landmarks. The dependencies leave me with two free parameters ... which is consistent with the apparent situation that the final "S" curve is determined by the two parameters, $b_v$ and $L_{ki}$. Now, the $V_p$ relations reduce the free parameters to just one, but I can't find an interpretation of $d_{ki}$ (see above comment) that causes the target relation to fall out. There seems to be a piece of the puzzle that I'm just not seeing.

Comment: @Blue: I don't know if there is missing a -. 
d_ki is the "vertical" distance from the inflection point to the red arc, where L_ki/2 is. That is my problem too. There are no other mentioning of d_ki except from the equation I can't figure out. To make the equations for R_ki,1 and R_ki,2, it is assumed that d_ki = b_v/2. But that is not 100% accurate.

Comment: @Math9876: "vertical to red arc" is the worst option. :) Geometrically, "perpendicular to red arc" is best, as then the target is a [power of a pt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point) relation involving the center of the $R_{sp,3}$ arc & a family of circles. For $R_{sp,3}$ very large compared to $d_{ki}$, "vertical to red arc" is *approximately* "perpendicular to red arc", but this may not help. ... In any case, if the $V_p$ eqns are inaccurate, and you aren't sure about signs, then how strongly should we believe when you say the target eqn is "true" and gives "the correct result"?

Comment: @Blue: Sorry, i don’t know that much about the original equation and the figure - only what i can see. What i mean when i say the equation is “true”, is that it gives a correct result that is possible to draw in a CAD-program. I honestly don’t know how the equation is made, that is why i am asking. I think you can assume pretty much anything, as long as it fits with the figure.

Comment: @Blue: But bear in mind, that this equation was made over 50 years ago. So i don’t know, if the engineer used different helping tools or where thinking in a different way?

Comment: @Math9876: I'm now of a mind that this isn't a *mathematics* question, but an *engineering* one. (Maybe even a "mind-reading" one! :) In [my attempt at an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4170558/409), I can only get within 3 or 4 degrees of freedom of the formula, with no intuition about what additional assumptions might help. So, I echo Ripi2's comment in suggesting that you might want to pose this to the folks at [Engineering.SE](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/). Someone there may be more familiar with the nuances of the formula and any unspoken assumptions or approximations.

Comment: I can't understand the numbers you gave as example. I'm starting to think that this is not a plan view, but a section skecht about superelevation (aka "cant") transition. Please, post the link to where you got the info, no matter which language it uses.

Comment: @Ripi2: It is just a plan view. But here is the link: https://vejregler.dk/h/7e0fba84-06dd-483b-898a-c7b3e3affaa1/vd20170120?showExact=true - if you want it as a PDF, then download the danish version, do not download the english version as it is not updated and some of the chapters are missing. The equations are in chapter "2.3.2 Begrænsningslinjen mod venstresvingssporet" under section "Kilestrækning".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a reimagining of OP's figure:

[image]

(In OP's figure, the "red arc" extends from $B$ to $G$. The portion to the left of $C$ is irrelevant here; so, for the purposes of this discussion, the "red arc" simply connects $C$ to $G$.)

To simplify notation, define
$$r := R_{sp,3} \qquad s := R_{ki,1} \qquad t := R_{ki,2} \qquad\quad c := \frac12b_v \quad m := \frac14 L_{ki} \qquad\qquad d := d_{ki} $$
Also, let $R$, $S$, $T$ be the centers of the arcs of respective radii $r$, $s$, $t$. Let the measures of the central angles be $2\theta$ at $R$, $2\phi$ at $T$, and $2\theta+2\phi$ at $S$.

Taking OP's $L_{ki}/2$ measurements to indicate horizontal distances between landmark points on the roadway ($C$, $D$, $E$ in the figure), we readily determine
$$\begin{align}
2m &= s(\sin2\theta+\sin2\phi) \tag1 \\
2m &= t \sin2\phi \tag2
\end{align}$$
Vertically, we find
$$\begin{align}
2c &= r - (r-s)\cos2\theta-(s+t)\cos2\phi+t \\
\to\qquad c &= r\sin^2\theta+t\sin^2\phi + s\sin(\phi+\theta)\sin(\phi-\theta) 
\tag3
\end{align}$$

These equations impose dependencies that reduce our collection of parameters from seven $(r, s, t; c, m; \theta, \phi)$ to some choice of four. For instance, we can solve for the radii in terms of the angles and horizontal/vertical offsets:
$$\begin{align}
r &= \sec\phi\csc^2\theta\sec(\phi-\theta) (
c \cos\phi\cos(\phi-\theta) - m\sin(2\phi-\theta)) \\
s &= m \csc(\phi+\theta)\sec(\phi-\theta)\\ 
t &= m \csc\phi\sec\phi
\end{align} \tag4$$
From here ... It's not quite clear how to proceed.

OP has additional relations we can write as
$$\frac1s - \frac1r \;= \frac1v =\; \frac1t - \frac1{r+2c} \tag5$$
where $v := V_p^2/108$ (and where we deduce that OP's "$\pm$" must be "$+$", since $t$ must be larger than $s$, as the $s$-arc makes a sharper turn than the $t$-arc). However, OP has commented "To make the equations for [$s$ and $t$], it is assumed that [$d=c$]. But that is not $100\%$ accurate." But applying $d=c$ to the target relation ($(\star)$ below) implies $d=c=0$, so the assumption is inconsistent with the target, which suggests that there are other layers of approximation going on. So, $(5)$ doesn't seem *directly* applicable here. Even if it were, by introducing an additional parameter $v$, the two equations in $(5)$ only reduce the number of free parameters to $3$; and it's not clear (to me) which might be subject to approximation.

As for the target relation itself, OP's rendering of it is inconsistent with the figure given, as it makes $d_{ki}$ *larger* than $R_{sp,3}$, which is one of the largest radii. Presumably, the relation should be a subtraction. Moreover, to ensure $d_{ki}$ is positive, we must take the "$\pm$" to be "$-$". Thus, it would appear that the target "should be"
$$d = r - \sqrt{r(r-2c)} \qquad\to\qquad (d-r)^2 = r(r-2c) \tag{$\star$}$$
The right-hand version is tantalizing in that it suggests a [power of a point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point) situation, in which $D$ lives on a circle orthogonal to a family of circles whose line-of-centers is the perpendicular bisector of the $2c$ segment:

[image]

In this situation, the $d$ segment (OP's $d_{ki}$) is an *extension* of $\overline{RD}$ that meets $\bigcirc R$, so that $(\star)$ asserts $|RD|^2=r(r-2c)$. One can show (I used coordinates) that this is equivalent to the condition
$$c r = 2 (r - s) s \sin^2(\phi+\theta) =2m(r-s)\tan(\phi+\theta) \tag6$$
where $r$ and $s$ can be rewritten via $(4)$, if desired.

Unfortunately, OP has commented that the $d$ segment *is not* orthogonal to the red arc (ie, is not an extension of $\overline{RD}$), but rather the *vertical distance* from $D$ to that arc. The messiness of the counterpart of $(6)$ for that situation exceeds my patience to TeX-ify it, so for now I'll leave its derivation as an exercise to the reader.

I'm inclined to wonder if maybe part of the engineer's genius here is to *approximate* the vertical distance by the orthogonal-to-arc one, leveraging the power of a point formula to simplify calculations. After all, OP has commented that $r$ tends to be on the order of $500$m, while $d$ is in the neighborhood of $1.5$m; at those scales, the computational error from the different interpretations of $d$ may be "acceptable".

Not that it really matters. I'm at a loss for how to arrive at even the nicer relation $(6)$. (Fiddling in GeoGebra shows that $D$ is *not* on the green circle for arbitrary values of the free parameters; more conditions are needed to lock this in.) Nor do I have the intuition to see why it would be an appropriate approximator. (I guess that's why I'm a mathematician, not an engineer.)

Without more information or insight, this is about as far as I can go.

---

Some additional thoughts ...

The flip side of my saying $(\star)$ implies "$c=d=0$" when $c=d$ is that $(\star)$ could alternatively imply $r=\infty$ when $c=d$. That is, the $c=d$ condition behind the approximations in $(5)$ effectively assumes "$r$ is large" (compared to other parameters). I suspect that this assumption also drives the target relation $(\star)$ ... which is to say: I don't believe $(\star)$ is a derivable geometric fact, but a contrived computational convenience.

Even so, let me cover one more bit of geometry:

[image]

Let the horizontal from my point $E$ and the vertical from $D$ meet at $D'$. Then
$$|D'D|=2m\tan\phi \tag{A.1}$$

Now, for the contrivance(s). **Beware of vigorously waving hands!**

For "large" $r$ ...

- The red arc is "flat", so that path $CDE$ becomes a "symmetric" $S$-curve that places $D$ at the vertical half-way mark of the $2c$ segment. This gives us
  $$c \approx |D'D| = 2m\tan\phi \tag{A.2}$$
- The central angle at $R$ is "small", so that $\theta\approx 0$ and thus
  $$c\approx 2m\tan(\phi+\theta) \tag{A.3}$$
- Now, if $r$ is large *compared to $s$* then we can write $1-\dfrac{s}{r}\approx 1$, so that
  $$c\approx 2m\left(1-\frac{s}{r}\right)\tan(\phi+\theta) \tag{A.4}$$
  But this is simply (though only approximately) $(6)$, which is equivalent to the target $(\star)$; I'll write this as
  $$|RD|^2 = r(r-2c) \tag{A.5}$$
- Finally, the target $d$ segment —defined by OP as the vertical distance from $D$ to the "red arc"— is, as described before, approximated by the extension of $|DR|$ that meets that arc, so that $|DR|\approx r-d$, giving
  $$(r-d)^2 \approx r(r-2c) \tag{A.6}$$
  as (approximately) desired.

This loosey-goosey approach almost-certainly doesn't pass muster with numerical analysts (of which I am not one), but it might at least serve as a scaffolding for a rigorous treatment.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will accept this as an answer, as i think this is the closest we will get to a derivation of the equation :-)

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand it **at present time**.

The radius of curvature of a curve with cartesian equation $y=f(x)$ is known to be:

$$R(x)=\dfrac{(1+f'(x)^2)^{3/2}}{f''(x)}\tag{1}$$

In our case where

$$f(x)=\sqrt{x(x+b)}\tag{2}$$

(whose curves are hyperbolas), the radius of curvature is

$$R_b(x)=\frac{1}{2b^2}\left(8x^2+8bx+b^2\right)^{3/2}\tag{3}$$

The corresponding curves grow like $kx^3$ and (almost) cover the first quadrant.

[image]

*Fig. 1: (abscissas: distances ; ordinates: radii of curvature) Determination of an adequate value of $b$ for the connecting arc, being known the initial (resp. final) radius of curvature $R'=100$ (resp. $R''=300$). Among all candidates (the arc of curves situated between the two red lines), only one will correspond to a given length ; for example if we desire a curve length $2$ meters (to be read on the $x$ axis), we should take $b \approx 4$ (probably unrealistic values, I agree ; our aim here is understanding/agreeing on the principle).*

Otherwise said, Fig. 1 is a kind of nomogram allowing, through the determination of a certain curve to get the good value of parameter $b$, and then use equation (2).

What do you think about all this interpretation ?

Comment: The ± sign in x±b depends on whether the curve of R_sp,3 and R_ki,1 turns the same direction or not (the s-shape).
Which again depends of the road, if it's in a left or right turning curve. But it's different from each time.

Comment: A realistic number for your constants a, b and d would be: a = 0,016875, b = 3,5 and d = 3,5. Both b and d are = b_v

Comment: To be honest, i am not a hardcore mathematician, but it looks better and better. I am still not sure, that it is the radius of curvature of a curve, since i still believe it is just a circular curve.

Comment: I have read your comment. Besides, I have somewhat modified the legend of the figure in order to eliminate any ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

The path model is clear so far.. ok for me to start understanding/interpreting. There could be typos with given labels:

At the end of interpretation, we should be able to state what the distances and acceleration are given and resulting equation is for path going above center line.

Basically, $d_k$ depends on R which again depends on acceleration due to $V_p$

$R_{k1}, R_{k2}$ are radii or $y$ coordinate on either side of designed inflection point at center.In other words with this point, an odd function describes the curve.

Curve $R_{sp,1}$ transitions to $R_{sp,3}$ through a point of inflection. Likewise $R_{sp,2}$ transitions to $R_{sp,4}$ through a point of inflection. The indicated vertical line is not labelled.

$L_{bu}/2$ is length designed between inflection and horizontal tangent point of merge completion where the vehicle resumes pure x- velocity without acceleration.

At distance $dki$ there is an inflection point maneuver designed on the center line of the road on x-axis.

To find $d_k$ following quadratic equation has been solved :

The first and second roots  are

$$d_{ki1} = R_{sp,3} + \sqrt{R_{sp,3} \cdot (R_{sp,3} \pm b_v)};\;d_{ki2} = R_{sp,3} - \sqrt{R_{sp,3} \cdot (R_{sp,3} \pm b_v)} \tag 1$$

we can find sum and product and form quadratic equation that contains both these roots $d_{ki}$:

$$ d_k^2 - 2 R_{sp,3} \; d_k \mp R_{sp,3}= 0 \tag 2 $$

Radial correction/compensation is due to influence of a lateral acceleration, follows a parallelly connected electric resistances model or pattern ( effective less than least radius etc). 108 could be some permissible limit acceleration value. Radius $ R_{ki,1} $ has no influence of acceleration. $R_{ki,2}$ takes acceleration into account.

$$ \dfrac{1}{R_{ki,2}}=\dfrac{1}{R_{sp,3 \pm b_v}}+ \dfrac{108}{V_p^2} \tag3 $$

We can continue through comments if you wish.

Comment: 108 is a factor that includes lateral acceleration and units conversion.

Comment: Can you explain where that quadratic comes from? $d_{ki}$ is not a radius, but a distance (or $y$ coordinate in the sketch). And notice that while tangent-continuity is granted between two circles, curvature (radius sign in roads parlance)  is not (concave vs convex)

Comment: @Ripi: Thanks, noted... you meant curves, there are no circles here.

Comment: In roads horizontal design the only curves considered are straights, circumferences and clothoids (Euler's spiral). Adjacent elements have the same tangent. If using clothoids then second derivatives (curvature) are same too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't think you need to think all the acceleration into the equations. It should just be purely geometry (but i am not a mathematician, so maybe it does matter?). 
And Ripi2 is right, there are only straights, circumferences and clothoids. (Even though there are only circular arcs and straight lines in this specific case)